# How to feed standard input and dump into file at the same time?

Tags: pipe

I would like to feed a command with standard input and dump that standard input into the file at the same time. This is just failed attempt:

```
read | tee dump.txt
```

this command is waiting for standard input. I expect whatever I input to be fed to `read` AND to be dumped into dump.txt. How can I do it?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Piping into a plain `read` is not really giving you any benefits. Anyway, what about just swapping the pipe around? `tee dump.txt | read`

Comment: read is an example of some other command, just to show a command with standard input. In reality instead of read it's `lpr` command which is taking raw input from std and printing it. What I need is to tap that communication and dump input into file as well.

Comment: swapping the pipe is almost doing what I want, except that I need an additional newline in order to finish input. Which is not good.

Comment: The additional newline is needed because of `read`. Try with e.g. `cat` instead, which will read until you close the stream by pressing Ctrl+D (or simply when the piped output ends).

Comment: but `read` alone doesn't need double newlines...

Comment: I can't really explain to you why it behaves like that (interesting question though), but it's a clear observation, I think. Asked a new question about that [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/952048/367990), maybe it will be answered. So does it work that way with your real command?

Answer (score 0):

Swap the pipe around: first get the output through `tee` to save a copy in a file while also replicating it on its standard output again, then pipe that into your actual command.

I use `cat` here instead because it takes indefinite amounts of input and doesn't quit after the first line (plus additional newline, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/952051/367990) for an explanation of that) like `read`:

```
echo something | tee dump.txt | cat
```