# "read" command waiting for additional newline if input comes through pipe

Tags: command-line, bash, pipe

If I simply run `read` it reads one line and immediately exits when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed.

```
$ read
typing something here
$
```

However, when I pass the input through a pipe, e.g. from `cat`, `read` behaves differently and keeps running until it encounters the second newline:

```
$ cat | read
typing first line
typing second line
$
```

Can anyone explain why it is this way?

PS: This question was inspired by [How to feed standard input and dump into file at the same time?](https://askubuntu.com/q/952040/367990)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have anything to do with the newline.

If you run your command using `strace`, you will find out that the `cat` will receives a `SIGPIPE` at the end, before being closed:

```
$ strace cat | read

...
someOutput
...
+++ killed by SIGPIPE +++
```

1. First `cat` command gets to run .
2. Then you type something in for the first time and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. What you have typed will be piped to the `read`.
4. `cat` is still running and waiting for a EOF.
5. You type something else and then hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> agian.
6. This time, it can't be piped to `read`, because there is no `read` anymore waiting for input (it has been closed after first pipe) unless you run it like this:

   ```
   cat | while read line; do echo $line; done;
   ```
7. `cat` will receives a `SIGPIPE` and gets closed.

> A process receives a SIGPIPE when it attempts to write to a pipe (named or not) or socket of type SOCK_STREAM that has no reader left. [[1]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84813/what-makes-a-unix-process-die-with-broken-pipe)

Receiving `SIGPIPE` happens *after* when second pipe happens.

For example consider `yes` command, because a command like `yes` pipes something fast and repeatedly:

```
yes | read
```

it gets closed immediately after the second pipe, pay attention to the two `write()` calls:

```
close(3)                                = 0                    
write(1, "y\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\n"..., 8192) = 8192          
write(1, "y\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\n"..., 8192) = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe) 
--- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=3542, si_uid=1000} ---
+++ killed by SIGPIPE +++
```

Although, because `yes` command is too fast you might see more than of two `write()` calls, however if you run it several times you will see at least two calls and never one.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, this has something to do with line buffering, i.e. `cat` only tries to send whole lines through the pipe as soon as the ENTER key gets pressed. `read` exits after the first line already, but `cat` only notices that when it tries to use the pipe again, not earlier?

Comment: Yes, the second time when it tries to pipe the second line it receives a `SIGPIPE` and get closed.

Comment: Uhm... but I just found out that `cat` actually isn't line buffered at all: https://superuser.com/a/896684/418736 - now I'm confused.

Comment: Have you tried running `strace cat | read`? Or running `strace cat` and sending a SIGPIPE (`kill -13` ) to its PID? I'm not sure about the buffering, but from inspecting the `strace` outputs, that is how it's working.

Comment: I tried that and also think it *looks* like some kind of line buffering, but apparently `cat` should not do that. I don't know.

Comment: Try this: `cat <whatever> | grep ^ --line-buffered` and use it in place of `cat`.